# Does my boss have to meet with me after I have resigned?

Tags: management, resignation

I recently gave my 3 weeks notice to my boss over the phone as he was working from home to let him know that I have accepted another job. My boss initially was blindsided by the news, and asked if the company could offer me anything to stay, but once I told him about the position and how it's a growth opportunity for me, he accepted it. The next day he was back to his usual self and was supportive of my decision and wished me the best in my new job. My boss works in a separate office and visits his employees when he needs to.

What's really bothering me though is that he is yet to come and meet me in person after I handed in my resignation. We have always had a great relationship, and I consider him a mentor. So far, we have only been emailing and talking to each other on the phone about the next steps before I leave. I understand that he is currently busy working on finding my replacement to take over from me as manager, but it does bother me that he has not come by to talk to me in person.

Is it necessary for a boss to visit his/her employee, following their resignation announcement?

Comment: No it is not necessary.

Comment: What does he have to gain by talking to you in person?  What do you feel you need from him that you would need to see him in person?

Comment: Thank you both! It's just that this is my first job after university where I resigned and wasn't sure what the protocol is from one's boss. Thanks for letting me know!:)

Comment: There almost certainly isn't a legal requirement for this. Beyond that, it mostly comes down to professionalism, which is largely subjective (whether we think he should probably wouldn't help your situation).

Comment: "What's really bothering me though is that he is yet to come and meet me in person after I handed in my resignation."  it means utterly nothing.  Forget about it and move on.  "Is it necessary for a boss to visit his/her employee, following their resignation announcement?"  Absolutely not.  I've never heard of such a thing - it sounds bizarre, and creepy.

Answer (score 4):

It's not really neccesary; I'm sure they can handle whatever official business still needs to be conducted by email or through people who are at your office location.

That said, I'd say it'd be expected to come say goodbye to a leaving close colleague, when they resign. But he might decide to do so on your last day, or going away party, or whatever the normal way is for your company.

And, of course, you don't have to wait for him to offer. If your company doesn't normally organise anything for those who leave, and your boss still hasn't mentioned anything about a personal goodbye in your last week, you can always invite him to your own going-away lunch, or just a goodbye coffee, or whatever.

You might have to head out to his location, but if he was a good mentor to you, that might be worth the effort.

Comment: Also, in the invitation, I would recommend telling him how good a boss and a mentor he has been and express appreciation for what he's done for you. Not only will that help the relationship between you two, he may be in a position to help you out in the future, and he'll be a lot more willing to help out.

Answer (score 0):

It's a personal decision for your boss, there is no need to meet with you in this circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

You require a formal acceptance from your boss (or organisation).

Apart from this I do understand that there was good relationship and rapport between you and your boss and the emotional attachment made you feel a direct meeting with your boss (maybe your inner self is not really prepared to move out of the current job and organisation. it happens sometimes)

My recommendation is ask for a meeting with your boss at the earliest and talk, face to face.

Comment: In the US and some other countries your first point is not true. Formal notice is typically only required in locations with strict labour laws or for people with employment contracts.

Answer (score 0):

It is the **professional** thing to do, but it is not necessary.  It also depends largely on company policy.  How you feel about him or visa versa do not come into play.

Answer (score 0):

since he already knew that you will be leaving ,hence he already understand your situation.
**NOT** all companies have a farewell party ,maybe give him a note or something on the last day you are still with the company